# Custom information pages not using SEO friendly URLs in OpenCart

Tags: layout, opencart

I am having issues with the opencart layout override feature.  I have created a new information page and I set the layout override to "`test`". The route for this layout is `"information/test"`. The controller is in the right place, as is the template.  I gave the new page the seo-friendly url of `"test-page"`.

My issue is that if I type in `"domain.com/test-page"` it will get there, but it uses the regular information layout instead of my customized test layout.  I can type in `domain.com/index.php?route=information/test&information_id=119` and it will now show the page with the right layout.

Is there a way to have it go the customized layout page (`domain.com/index.php?route=information/test&information_id=119)` when I type in the seo-frindly URL that I created when I created the new information page.

My issue is I am trying to add a carousel to just one information page, while still using seo-friendly URLs.

Answer (score 2):

actually what you coded in template file `test.tpl` is **not a layout**, its actually a page accessed using `test.php` controller ,  and that page can be opened by accessing url `domain.com/index.php?route=information/test&information_id=119` as you already mentioned.

**How to create layout then ?**

You have already created layout named `test` by going to `System >> Design >> Layouts`, now go to module `carousel` and a module to test layout at say content-top , set your test-page layout override to test and now go to `domain.com/test-page` and you will see carousel at the top, this is how layout works. what you previously doing was creating a new page by duplicating information controller and template.

A similar discussion on opencart forum [Here](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=92308&p=371565)